# How to test a new random sequence in NIST Test Suite?

Tags: random, testng, nist

I have to test a random sequence using the NIST Test Suite. I have downloaded and run the tests on the files given in the data directory. It is working fine but when I tried to run it on a new random sequence, I am getting **igmac: UNDERFLOW** error. The random sequence is generated in Matlab using

```
bs=fix(randi([0 1],1,k));
```

and then saved as **.dat** file using

```
dlmwrite('bs.dat', bs);
```

I copied the bs.dat into the data folder and executed the test as follows. Can someone tell me what's wrong here?

ash@computer:~/Documents/NIST_Test_Original/sts-2.1.2$ ./assess 1000000
           G E N E R A T O R    S E L E C T I O N 
           ______________________________________

```
[0] Input File                 [1] Linear Congruential
[2] Quadratic Congruential I   [3] Quadratic Congruential II
[4] Cubic Congruential         [5] XOR
[6] Modular Exponentiation     [7] Blum-Blum-Shub
[8] Micali-Schnorr             [9] G Using SHA-1
```

Enter Choice: 0

```
    User Prescribed Input File: data/bs.txt

            S T A T I S T I C A L   T E S T S
            _________________________________

[01] Frequency                       [02] Block Frequency
[03] Cumulative Sums                 [04] Runs
[05] Longest Run of Ones             [06] Rank
[07] Discrete Fourier Transform      [08] Nonperiodic Template Matchings
[09] Overlapping Template Matchings  [10] Universal Statistical
[11] Approximate Entropy             [12] Random Excursions
[13] Random Excursions Variant       [14] Serial
[15] Linear Complexity

     INSTRUCTIONS
        Enter 0 if you DO NOT want to apply all of the
        statistical tests to each sequence and 1 if you DO.
```

Enter Choice: 0

```
     INSTRUCTIONS
        Enter a 0 or 1 to indicate whether or not the numbered statistical
        test should be applied to each sequence.

  123456789111111
           012345
  110000000000000


    P a r a m e t e r   A d j u s t m e n t s
    -----------------------------------------
[1] Block Frequency Test - block length(M):         128
```

Select Test (0 to continue): 0

How many bitstreams? 5

Input File Format:
    [0] ASCII - A sequence of ASCII 0's and 1's
    [1] Binary - Each byte in data file contains 8 bits of data

Select input mode:  0

```
 Statistical Testing In Progress.........

igamc: UNDERFLOW
igamc: UNDERFLOW
igamc: UNDERFLOW
igamc: UNDERFLOW
igamc: UNDERFLOW
 Statistical Testing Complete!!!!!!!!!!!!
```